# What is the order of Reynolds number inside the Compressor at cruise conditions?

Tags: jet-engine, cruise, compressor, reynolds-number

I am doing a CFD study on a probe that will be installed inside a compressor of a civil aircraft for my final year project. I need to know the Reynolds number inside a compressor at cruise conditions. Probably, if somebody has its variations along all the stages it will be really helpful. HPC /IPC/LPC any might do? I may also need the reference length chosen (which is usually the chord).

Thanks a lot in advance
Abhishek VERMA